# "SyntaxError: Unexpected token import" on truffle test

Tags: truffle, testing, import, mocha, unittesting

I get an "SyntaxError: Unexpected token import" error when I do 'truffle test'. I am trying to import a function declared in another file into the java-script test file. I have been searching about this issue for quite sometime and couldn't find any solution. Is this an issue with mocha testing on truffle ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

All it needed was to add a package.json file to the project directory with some babel dependencies and doing an 'npm install'. Also, adding a '.babelrc' file to the truffle project directory. Finally, adding some requires to truffle.js file.

package.json file

```
{
  "name": "game-token",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.17.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.23.0"
  }
}
```

.babelrc file

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-2", "stage-3"]
}
```

requires in truffle.js

```
require('babel-register');
require('babel-polyfill');
```

Comment: also requires babel-polyfill in your devDependencites:     "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",

Answer (score 6):

I tried i_robot's solution, and it almost* worked, I had to add:

```
require('babel-register')({
  ignore: /node_modules\/(?!zeppelin-solidity)/
});
require('babel-polyfill');
```

at the top of my truffle.js.  The ignore field is important!! In addition to adding babel-polyfill in my package.json dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.17.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.23.0",
    "bignumber.js": "^5.0.0",
    "bluebird": "^3.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "zeppelin-solidity": "1.6.0"
  }
```

.babelrc file

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-2", "stage-3"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't using es6 javascript, you can't use the `import` keyword. If you are using es6, maybe you don't have mocha set up correctly to understand or transpile down to es5 before you run your tests.

Comment: Are there any resources for setting up the mocha testing framework on truffle properly ? That would be very helpful.

Comment: You'll need to look into using webpack and babel to transpile your tests into a version of js that Mocha understands. Here's a guide: https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/wiki/Using-Truffle-and-Webpack-(beta). And here's a generic guide on using webpack and babel with Mocha: http://jamesknelson.com/testing-in-es6-with-mocha-and-babel-6/. I accept upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

I found it easier to use the `require` method.

src/utils.js:

```
exports.a = 3;
```

test/foo/testfile.js:

```
// Note the relative path from the current test file.
const utils = require('../../src/utils.js');
console.log(utils.a); // 3
```